# How to concatenate and print a list of integers?

Tags: haskell

Let's say I have a list `(x:xs)` of integers, so `(x:xs) :: Int`.

I want to concatenate and print those Integers on the same line. So when I do `printL [4,3,4]`, I want the function to give me `"434"` as output.

I tried this:

```
printL :: [Int] -> String
printL (x:xs) = chr x ++ printL xs
```

where my idea is that for every element in the list, it will take the head (so `x`). Convert it to a string with the `chr` function, and concatenate it with `printL xs` (where this will recursively do the same steps again).

As you can see I am stuck, and since I just started learning there must be a lot of errors.

Comment: Try `show x` instead of `chr x`: you don't need to convert a Unicode codepoint into a character, but a number into its decimal digits. That's done by `show`. Also, don't forget to add a base case for the recursion `printL [] = ...`. (When you'll be more fluent with Haskell you will write `printL = concatMap show`, but for the moment it helps practicing with the basics).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> where my idea is that for every element in the list, it will take the head (so `x`).

Eventually if you work with recursion it will call `printL` with an empty list, so you need to cover at least two cases: one for an empty list `[]`, and one for a non-empty list `(x:xs)`.

> Convert it to a string with the `chr` function

[**`chr :: Int -> Char`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:chr) convert a given `Int` value to the unicode *character* with as codepoint the value you passed as parameter. It thus will *not* create a `String`, and `0` will *not* be mapped to the `'0'` character, but to the `'\NUL'` character. You can work with [**`intToDigit :: Int -> Char`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:intToDigit) for this.

> and concatenate it with `printL xs`

`chr x` returns a `Char`, so you can not concatenate it. You can use `(:)` to prepend it to the list of `Char`s produced by `printL`.

So we can fix these three problems, and implement this as:

```
import Data.Char(intToDigit)

printL :: [Int] -> String
printL [] = ""
printL (x:xs) = intToDigit x : printL xs
```

The recursion pattern we here use is equivalent to a [**`map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map) with `intToDigit` as mapping function, so we can rewrite this to:

```
import Data.Char(intToDigit)

printL :: [Int] -> String
printL = map intToDigit
```